# I want to use Swiper methods in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, swiper.js

guys!

I have this project: [Picture with project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ohjDe.png)

When i click on the one of the left images,i want the main img of swiper to be the same...I'm thinking to use `swiper.slideTo(index, speed, runCallbacks)` but i can't use Swiper.slideTo(),i get a big Error.Any ideas or advice how to use swiper methods and properties in React?

Here is the code.Thank you!

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Modal } from "antd";
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from "swiper/react";
import SwiperCore, { Navigation, Pagination } from "swiper";
import "swiper/swiper-bundle.css";
import "swiper/components/zoom/zoom.less";
import { TransformComponent, TransformWrapper } from "react-zoom-pan-pinch";
import { AiOutlineReload } from "react-icons/ai";
import { AiOutlinePlus } from "react-icons/ai";
import { AiOutlineMinus } from "react-icons/ai";
import logo from "./cart.png";
import { IoMdHeartEmpty } from "react-icons/io";
import { AiFillHeart } from "react-icons/ai";

SwiperCore.use([Navigation, Pagination]);

const ModalImg = ({ setModalVisible, modalVisible, images }) => {
  const [change, setChange] = useState(false);
  const [clicked, setClicked] = useState(false);
  return (
    <Modal
      width={1200}
      centered
      visible={modalVisible}
      okButtonProps={{ style: { display: "none" } }}
      cancelButtonProps={{ style: { display: "none" } }}
      onCancel={() => setModalVisible(false)}
      style={{ position: "" }}
    >
      <div className="">
        <div className="flex w-full mt-7 border-t border-gray-200">
          <div className="w-1/5 h-full border-r border-gray-300 flex flex-wrap pt-5">
            {images &&
              images.map((arg, index) => {
                return (
                  <span
                    key={index}
                    className="border border-gray-50 hover:border-blue-500 mr-3  mb-4 "
                  >
                    <img
                      src={arg.url}
                      alt="fkc"
                      className="w-20 h-20  object-cover cursor-pointer p-1"
                    />
                  </span>
                );
              })}
          </div>
          <div className="w-full flex items-center justify-center pt-5">
            <Swiper
              spaceBetween={0}
              // loop={true}
              // speed={600}
              zoom={true}
              slidesPerView={1}
              navigation
              // pagination={{ clickable: true }}
              style={{ width: "400px" }}
            >
              {images &&
                images.map((arg) => {
                  return (
                    <div key={arg.public_id}>
                      <SwiperSlide>
                        <TransformWrapper defaultScale={1}>
                          {({ zoomIn, zoomOut, resetTransform, ...rest }) => (
                            <>
                              <TransformComponent>
                                <img
                                  id={arg.public_id}
                                  src={arg.url}
                                  alt="fck"
                                />
                              </TransformComponent>
                              <span className="flex mt-6 items-center justify-center w-full">
                                <span
                                  onClick={zoomIn}
                                  className="border hover:border-blue-500 rounded-full p-2 mx-4  text-gray-500  cursor-pointer"
                                >
                                  <AiOutlinePlus className="text-xl " />
                                </span>
                                <span
                                  onClick={zoomOut}
                                  className="border hover:border-blue-500 rounded-full p-2 mx-4  text-gray-500  cursor-pointer"
                                >
                                  <AiOutlineMinus className="text-xl" />
                                </span>
                                <span
                                  onClick={resetTransform}
                                  className="border hover:border-blue-500 rounded-full p-2 mx-4  text-gray-500  cursor-pointer"
                                >
                                  <AiOutlineReload className="text-xl" />
                                </span>
                              </span>
                            </>
                          )}
                        </TransformWrapper>
                      </SwiperSlide>
                    </div>
                  );
                })}
            </Swiper>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by `main img of swiper to be the same` ? clicking the image on the left but the swiper image will not change?

Comment: So,my left images are the same with the swiper images,but are completly independent.What i want is when i click on one of the left images, to get the index of the image,and put it in the state,then when the state is chaning,i want swiper to "slideTo"  the state index. I want to know how to add SlideTo method in Swiper-react.Thanks!